# nmcli - delete / replace DNS [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS]

Tags: networking, dns, nmcli

I have a problem with slow DNS queries while in VPN. Until the Problem is fixed, I want to delete / replace a specific DNS.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Change DNS in "Connections - System Settings" (UI) - Entered the new DNS, clicked "apply" => New DNS is displayed in UI (but nmcli still show the old DNS + the old DNS is used)
2. Try to change DNS via nmcli

**Step 1**

```
user@pc:~$ nmcli device modify enp36s0 ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
Connection successfully reapplied to device 'enp36s0'.
```

**Step 2**

```
user@pc:~$ nmcli device modify enp36s0 -ipv4.dns 1.2.3.4
Connection successfully reapplied to device 'enp36s0'.
```

But its not working: `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` still shows the old DNS Entries.

Comment: Could you post anon results of `nmcli` before and after connecting the VPN ?

Comment: What kind of VPN is used ? Is it OpenVPN ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @user4089 - but we've fixed the problems with the DNS now.